# How to get started with Oracle Endeca Commerce?

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, backend, endeca

We try to introduce this product into the existing online store, working with Java EE.

We understand, that this question is so global and we want to decide two tasks:

1. Install and setting software;
2. Create simple example for comprehension of this technology work's.

We already used:
      1. Oracle official documentation. It observes information about the possibilities and features of the product, without installation and configuration;
      2. Reading specialized forums. It didn't give absolutely no answers for our questions;
      3. view video on Youtube (Oracle official Channel). It gives us performance of business analysts work's and the main problem is not decidied.

We interesting for any information.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprised to hear that Oracle documentation didn't help in using Endeca (now known as "Guided Search").

Google for below documentation with appropriate Endeca version (say "11.1").

You can also find reference implementations available with the software like "Platform Services" and "Tools And Frameworks".

**Installation:**

- MDEXInstallGuide.pdf
- PlatServInstallGuide.pdf
- InstallGuide.pdf
- CASInstallGuide.pdf

**Learning:**

- GettingStartedGuide.pdf
- EndecaConceptsGuide.pdf
- AsmAppDevGuide.pdf
- BasicDevGuide.pdf
- DeploymentTemplateUsageGuide.pdf
- DevStudioHelp.pdf
- WorkbenchUserGuide.pdf

**Advanced:**

- AdvDevGuide.pdf
- PartialUpdatesGuide.pdf
- ForgeGuide.pdf
- CASDevGuide.pdf
- PerfTuningGuide.pdf
- URLOptimizationAPIJava.pdf
- LogServerReportGen.pdf
- WorkbenchAdminGuide.pdf
- XMgrExtensionsUserGuide.pdf

Comment: @Stanislav Zazhogin - Hello! Hope the answer helped you.

Comment: Yes, it was very helpful! Thank you!